# How to parse through a row using information pulled from a user form

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, runtime

I am attempting to create a userform which takes input from userform1 and passes it to userform2 which displays the information belonging to that set of data on userform2. The problem is that once the overall category is selected from row 1 (CATBOX), I need to limit the parser to the subcomponents in row 2 as there are other subcomponents in other categories on the same row. Each Category in row 1 is a series of merged cells.

I have already tried using 'find' to find the value of `userform1!CATBOX` and return the position to get the starting column.  Then I tried to find the range of the merged cell so that I could get the end point.  I then tried to limit the parser to the range of columns on row 2 to collect my information.  I included the last bit of code to simply display the values of the start and end points onto userform2, it is not necessary to my code.

```
With ActiveSheet

    Set ra = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=UserForm1!CATBOX.Value, After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Set rng = Range(ra)

    If rng.MergeCells Then

        Set rng = rng.MergeArea
        Set rngStart = rng.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rngEnd = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    End If


    Set rag = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "rag", True)
    With rag
        .Caption = rngStart.Address
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 50
    End With

    Set rag2 = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "rag2", True)
    With rag2
        .Caption = rngEnd.Address
        .Left = 70
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 50
    End With

    End With
```

The result I am looking to get is the ability to parse that second row of information limited to the range of columns established by the merged category above it.

Comment: A screenshot of your data would be useful here.

Comment: ..."Each Category in row 1 is a series of merged cells" is open to a few different interpretations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.Though the requirement and worksheet Data layout is not clear, It assumed as below. 
[image]
Code used may be modified to your requirement and may be moved from Change Event of CATBOX to any suitable event

```
Private Sub CATBOX_Change()
Dim Rng As Range, SubRng As Range
Dim Rw As Long, ColSt As Long, ColEnd As Long, i As Long, ScatNo As Long
Dim Rag As Object

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set Rng = .Rows(1).Find(What:=UserForm1.CATBOX.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set Rng = Rng.MergeArea
Set rngstart = Rng.Cells(1, 1)
Set rngEnd = Rng.Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count)
Rw = Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count
ColSt = Rng.Column
ColEnd = Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
Debug.Print Rw, ColSt, ColEnd

Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Rw, ColSt), .Cells(Rw, ColEnd))
ScatNo = 0
   For Each SubRng In Rng
        If SubRng.Value <> "" Then
        ScatNo = ScatNo + 1
        Set Rag = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Scat" & ScatNo)
        Rag.Caption = SubRng.Value
        Rag.Left = 70
        Rag.Width = 50
        Rag.Top = ScatNo * 30
        End If
   Next
End With
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is exactly what I was looking for and exactly what I was trying to describe!  I apologize for not initially including a photo of my data, but it totally slipped my mind.  Thank you for your time!